# How to make styler object to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-science

I want to replace nan in html to blank space but when I'm using s.replace I'm getting

> AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'replace'

This is what I was trying

```
s=b.style.apply(lambda x: ["background-color: green"]*n if x['MessageType']== '[43503]' else ["background-color: white"]*n, axis = 1)

s= s.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
s.to_html("SORTED.html")
```

Comment: Where the `Styler` object comes from? Is it from a public library or you define it by your own? It's hard to provide an answer with limited context. Maybe you can just try to cast `s` to string before like: `s= str(s).replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)`

Comment: Do replace before style apply.